# What is the definition of absolute maximum ratings?

Tags: analog, circuit-design, datasheet

What is the definition absolute maximum ratings? Does it vary from manufacturer to manufacturer?

Comment: One may conclude that MTBF declines  rapidly over these limits. Even using rated 100% power , current or voltage is a stress factor that accelerates failure, so a prudent designer wil choose a reasonable margin of >=20% below rated specs which are below AMR's

Comment: Nope. Keeping on keep on...

Comment: <= - work as per spec sheet (usually).| > = Are you feeling lucky, punk?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, short story is the definition of absolute maximum rating does vary from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Most every manufacture (of those sampled) will give a variation of this warning:

> Stresses beyond those listed under Absolute Maximum Ratings may cause
> permanent damage to the device.

Then proceed to tell you that this might happen over time:

Exposure to absolute maximum rating

> conditions for extended periods may affect device reliability.

If international standards count for anything here is IEC60134 which "standardizes" the definition of absolute maximum ratings:

IEC60134 paragraph 4: Absolute maximum rating system This section states:

> “Absolute maximum ratings are limiting values of operating and
> environmental conditions applicable to any electronic device of a
> specified type as defined by its published data, which should not be
> exceeded under the worst probable conditions.
>
> These values are chosen by the device manufacturer to provide
> acceptable serviceability of the device, taking no responsibility for
> equipment variations, environmental variations, and the effects of
> changes in operating conditions due to variations in the
> characteristics of the device under consideration and of all other
> electronic devices in the equipment.”

Here is where it gets really boring, but I threw this up for comparison

Analog says that their absolute maximum ratings won't kill the part instantly but it will degrade over time:

> Stresses above those listed under Absolute Maximum Ratings may cause
> permanent damage to the device. This is a stress rating only;
> functional operation of the device at these or any other conditions
> above those indicated in the operational section of this specification
> is not implied. Exposure to absolute maximum ratings for extended
> periods may affect device functionality.

They also say on many of their chips its process based.

> The maximum supply voltage that can be applied to an op amp is
> determined by the fabrication process. It refers to the instantaneous
> value, not the average or final value. Low voltage CMOS op amps from
> Analog Devices, Inc., are typically limited to 6 V, whereas high
> voltage bipolar parts are limited to 36 V.

Source: [Analog App Note MS-2551](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/technical.../MS-2251.pdf)

Linear Technology gives a standard warning and reliability:

> Stresses beyond those listed under Absolute Maximum Ratings may cause
> permanent damage to the device. Exposure to any Absolute Maximum
> Rating condition for extended periods may affect device reliability
> and lifetime.

Maxim Electronics gives the standard warning and that it will affect reliability:

> Stresses beyond those listed under “Absolute Maximum Ratings” may
> cause permanent damage to the device. These are stress ratings only,
> and functional operation of the device at these or any other
> conditions beyond those indicated in the operational sections of the
> specifications is not implied. Exposure to absolute maximum rating
> conditions for extended periods may affect device reliability.

Texas Instruments is the same:

> Stresses beyond those listed under absolute maximum ratings may cause
> permanent damage to the device. These are stress ratings only, and
> functional operation of the device at these or any other conditions
> beyond those indicated under recommended operating conditions is not
> implied. Exposure to absolute-maximum-rated conditions for extended
> periods my affect device reliability.

The exception is Rohm and they say you can't exceed the ratings ever or you'll cause damage:

> Absolute maximum ratings are conditions that should never be exceeded,
> even momentarily. For example, supplying a voltage over the maximum
> rating and/or using in environments outside of the temperature range
> may cause deterioration of IC characteristics or even damage.

Source: [Rohm Absolute Maximum Ratings](http://www.rohm.com/web/eu/electronics-basics/opamps/absolute-maximum-ratings/)

Comment: Rohm is not really different; all the quotes above differentiate between "**beyond** AMR" and "exactly at AMR" conditions.

Comment: +5 :-) - a nice list of examples.

Comment: Even though the words are different, the *meaning* of all of the examples you cite is exactly the same: If you ever exceed any AMR, the manufacturer will no longer guarantee the future operation of the device. What is the point you are trying to make here?

Comment: They are not all *exactly* the same. I put them all in one place so I could compare them. Rohm and analog are different. Yeah its a little obtuse, but you can see which ones are the same and which ones are different.

Comment: It would be helpful if manufacturers included a rating between AMR and Operating Conditions for "Part may sit under these conditions indefinitely without excess wear, though correct behavior would only be guaranteed if conditions are brought into the operating range."

Comment: The issue I have is the first statement says usually says beyond AMR will cause damage, and then the second statement says it will affect reliability. I don't think this correlates well with what is going on physically as some parts might die slowly and some quickly.

Comment: @supercat you're right it would be nice, but it would require more verification from the manufacturer which would increase the part's cost. It's also not that easy to define the various failure modes will enough to make definite statements. Take your favorite chip that has commercial and industrial temperature options. Often these are the same chip, some are just run through more rigorous validation to prove they'll work at the extended range. They also cost more because of that extra validation and warranty support.

Comment: @Littleman: It shouldn't cost anything to, at minimum, indicate which conditions will stress the part even if limits aren't exceeded, and which ones could be endured essentially forever if kept within limits.  Further, even if a manufacturer doesn't specify exact performance it could still offer guidelines (e.g. each X-degree reduction in temperature would roughly double the amount of time until the part would fail from a certain cause, until it reached the point where some other failure would occur first).

Comment: @Littleman: If it would cost a certain amount to reduce a part's temperature by 10 degrees, for example, that may be worthwhile if it would prevent a part from failing when it otherwise would have, but not if the temperature would have no effect on the part's lifetime.

Comment: For some conditions, an "extended period" could be milliseconds.

Comment: @immibis Thats why I don't know why they say "could affect reliability". Basically what there saying is, if you go over the ratings your part could die. In reality its more like if you go over the ratings, your part will die.

Comment: @supercat you also have to get into compound degradation modes.  One easy example (usually dealt with by derating) would be running at 99% of V_AMR, 1&deg;C below T_AMR.  When you start thinking about the combination of V_supply, V_input and R_Load it only gets worse - you end up having to test a huge parameter space

Comment: @ChrisH: There is a huge parameter space, but in most cases only a small portion will involve any meaningful reduction in reliability at all.  It may not be practical to specify the exact boundaries, but many applications could benefit from being able to use areas that are nowhere near the boundaries.

Comment: @supercat That's true.  But the market size (normalised to test costs and taking into account failure risk) is probably not far from optimal in a current system that leaves a grey area rather than being more specific as you (and I) might like.

Comment: @ChrisH: Some devices are specified pretty well, but most would be almost useless to anyone who wasn't willing to make educated guesses about behavior.  Fortunately most devices actually behave in ways that allow educated guesses to be pretty good.

Comment: @supercat, if it takes time, it costs money. It most certainly takes time to discover and document these things. Not to mention maintaining the documentation. I'm with you that datasheets could be better, but I've been doing this long enough that I'm just happy if I get somewhat reliable numbers in the first place for the major functions. What you're asking for is, in my experience, "gravy" or nice to have data.

Comment: @Littleman: If a part's "recommended operating conditions" specifies VDD=2.0-5.5V, but then specifies that it will draw no more than 1.0mA at 2.0V or 3.0mA at 5.0V, should an engineer be entitled to assume that the part will draw less than 100mA at 5.1V?  Or for that matter 3.5V?  I wouldn't expect a manufacturer to sample every part at every allowable voltage, but a manufacturer should be able to say e.g. that in a good part operated within the allowable range, there would be no plausible reason for a 10% increase in supply voltage to cause more than e.g. a 25% increase in supply current.

Comment: @Littleman: Given such a spec, along with the measurement at 2.0V, one could figure that at 2.5V, current would be below 1.7mA, and at 3.0V it would be below2.6mA.  One wouldn't know how much below, but especially at 2.5V even a very conservative estimate that scales up from the current draw at 2.0V may be more useful than nothing.  I would expect that most designs would easily allow for such conservative estimates.

Answer (score 5):

Semiconductor manufacture and specification is not exact, there is an element of probability involved. Any component type will have a spread of values for which it 'blows up' according to some definition.

There are three broad groups of users, which have different interpretations of the risk involved in component failure.

There is the 'no risk' group, like automotive, military, aviation, medical.

There is the 'reasonable commercial risk' group, most industrial and commercial manufacturers, and hobbyists who just want to build stuff that works and keeps working.

Then there is the 'turn it up till it blows up, then back off a bit' group of overclockers and Tesla coil builders, who know what they're doing, for whom component failure is part of the normal operating envelope.

AMRs, Absolute Maximum Ratings, are for the first two groups.

If you want your stuff to keep working without trouble, then plan to keep all parameters within the AMRs. If your recommended rail voltage is 15v, and the AMR is 18v, then set your rail crowbar at 17v. You may have one IC that kept working at 20v, lucky you. Or did it keep working, was there some degradation that wasn't immediately apparent? If you plan to exceed any AMRs, then plan to fault-find, and replace.

Answer (score 4):

The AMR (Absolute Maximum Ratings) are a set of parameters that define the boundary of reliable device operations. The primary purpose of them is to avoid manufacturer'r liability. The reliability is formulated in terms of certain probability of device failure, which depends on class of the device (consumer, industrial, automotive, MIL-883, medical, etc.), and usually is not disclosed to public.

The set of AMR parameters is determined for every product by device reliability engineers, who carefully examine all operational parameters over the entire designated range of operational conditions, such as mechanical/thermal fatigue, electromigration, etc., and come up with  numbers. Then this set of numbers is validated on real device samples using accelerated aging methods. Then technical marketing people fudge this number to meet customer's expectations and avoid potential liabilities.

The parameters are absolute in the sense that they are defined under the worst combination of all parameters, over all process corners. As such, if a device temperature is kept at or below nominal, exceeding maximum voltage wouldn't kill it, and exceeding device operational frequency might result in a fully functional device. That's why overclocklers do exist. However, the distribution function of these inter-dependencies are usually unknown and would take too much engineering effort to determine, so a manufacturer simply prefer to void any guarantee if one of parameters is exceeded in customer's application.

For really big customers there is some room for negotiations. If, say some reliability parameter was defined based on 1,000,000 hours of operations (~ 100 years), but the customer plans for only 5 years of service, the rating can be changed. But it takes a special effort to come up with reliability PDF to determine this and approve the application.

Comment: Reliable device operation is guaranteed only inside the Recommended Operating Conditions. When going beyond the ROCs, but not yet exceeding the AMRs, the device might not work, but will not be permanently damaged.

Comment: @CL., you are technically right. But the scope of this question doesn't seem to warrant delving into this kind of details. All I wanted is to point out an **objective** probabilistic nature of the ratings with individual evaluation of each product, and to some **subjectivity** on how this parameter is conveyed to customers, as some opposite to a collection of technical marketing blurbs. Details are usually a well kept secret, because they determine competitiveness of a product in global marketplace.

Answer (score 3):

### There are three operating zones here

The ratings of a part can be divided into three zones: "nominal" (or Recommended Operating Conditions), "off-nominal" (outside of Recommended Operating Conditions but not outside of the Absolute Maximum Ratings), and "magic smoke likely" (outside of the Absolute Maximum Ratings).

Within the "nominal" zone, part operation to specifications is guaranteed within the manufacturer's acceptable failure probabilities.  We design to operate within this range of conditions as we know from the datasheet how the part will behave within this zone.

Within the "off-nominal" zones, the part will attempt to operate, but it may not meet all datasheet specifications, or may have a shortened lifetime that the manufacturer no longer considers acceptable.  Off-nominal conditions may exist transiently during system fault recovery, or startup and shutdown situations, but should not be allowed to persist for any length of time as they may have an impact on operation.

Once you get to the "magic smoke likely" point, namely the AMRs, the reliability concerns go from long-term (shortened lifetime) to short-term (it fails on your bench or becomes an infant mortal in customer hands).  Obviously, the warranty is void at this point -- folks like overclockers who don't care about the warranty and know the risks they're taking though may push parts outside of specification with the aid of extra magic smoke control means (such as augmented cooling), however.

### Not all off-nominal operation is the same

There are several different possibilities for off-nominal conditions, depending on what type of part you're talking about; the most common ones in the semiconductor world are depicted in the voltage-temperature "box plot" shown below and also explained in more detail here, though.

[image: voltage-temperature box plot]

- The "On/Off (Power Ramp)" zone represents voltages below minimum operating voltage.  This happens every time you turn the thing on or off, or due to a supply brownout (because of say a flat battery).  Operation in this zone is not guaranteed: analog parts often will struggle to do much useful, and digital parts will simply get confused if they stay in this zone for a length of time.  Reset circuits (power-on, brown-out) are used in the digital world to keep parts in a known state while in this zone, but they have their own limitations at very low supply voltages.
- The "Cold Startup" zone represents excessively *cold* conditions, below minimum operating temperatures.  Many parts will still meet spec here even though they haven't been tested for this due to cost or testing limits, but some parts (bandgaps and oscillators are notorious for failing to start up properly at low temps in the analog world, while LCDs and other things with fluidics or chemistry going on simply won't work well at all in this zone) will refuse to operate properly here.
- The "Overvoltage (Supply Transient)" zone represents supply transients in excess of the maximum operating rating of the part, yet still survivable.  These typically shorten lifespan, but are otherwise not an issue, and are remnants of larger surges clamped by protection devices.
- Finally, the "Thermal Fault (Overtemperature Protection)" zone represents transient overtemperature conditions that are relieved by current limiting (in analog parts), speed throttling (in digital parts), or simply by an overtemperature shutdown.  Again, operation here shortens component lifespan.

Comment: Thermal is a big part of it, but not the only reason why you'd want to avoid crossing the AMR boundary. Electromigration is another reason. Even if you were to stabilize the part thermally, you could still reduce the lifetime.

Comment: @laptop2d -- agreed re: electromigration -- I was just giving extra cooling as an example of magic smoke control means, not as the be-all and end-all :)