# Help reading IR LED datasheet

Tags: voltage, led

I want to run 5 Vishay TSUS5402 LEDs continuously, but I'm not sure what the voltage and current should be. The datasheet is here:

https://www.vishay.com/docs/81056/tsus5400.pdf

I can't really see on the datasheet anything about continuous use, only pulse. Thanks for any help

Comment: Thanks everyone for the informative answers. Between here and an led array program I got it working. I feel I have a better understanding of LEDs now as I didn't realize the relationship between current and voltage was the way it is. Thanks again, I don't know what us noobs would do without knowledgeable people like yourselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure 4 gives the information you require.

[image]

*Figure 4. For a current of 100 mA you can expect a forward voltage of about 1.35 V.*

Note that \$ V_f \$ will have a spread. Design for current control, not voltage control.

Answer (score 1):

From the datasheet:

> **Absolute Maximum Ratings**
>   Forward current 150 mA

What's wrong with that?

EDIT: to make it clear: this is an **Absolute maximum**, you should definitely keep your current below that figure.
The datasheet here and there mentions 100mA as the operating conditions to which are referred other values. You should be able to operate your LED safely at that current

Comment: But at what voltage? I see 1.3, 1.7, 2.2 and 3.4. Under basic characteristics it says IF = 100 mA, tp = 20 ms for min 1.3 and max 1.7. Sorry, I'm just not used to so much info on a datasheet, regular LEDs don't usually have so much info.

Comment: Hi - Be careful quoting "Absolute Maximum Ratings" as being suitable for use in a design, *especially* when the OP is specifically looking for *continuous* usage. The OP's linked datasheet doesn't explain its meaning, but have you checked what the industry standard term "Absolute Maximum Ratings" means? When you do that research, you will see that this is **not** a figure which the OP should use, especially continuously :-( Here is a link from [Analog Devices](http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-50.html) to get you started. Notice the points about *continuous* and *margin*.

Comment: [continued] This topic here on EE.SE is also relevant: "[What is the definition of absolute maximum ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/324360/101852)".

Comment: @SamGibson i haven't said that somebody should use that figure in a design. That's an absolute maximum and such should be considered

Comment: @valerio_new - "*i haven't said that somebody should use that figure in a design*" Oh. But you put that figure in an answer and said "*What's wrong with that?*". So it seemed very clear that you *are* suggesting the OP to use it. Therefore some kind of misunderstanding is happening. If you *aren't* recommending the OP to use the value that you put in an answer, I suggest you edit the answer to make it clear that you *aren't* recommending it to the OP. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson is it more clear now?

Comment: @valerio_new - Thanks, it's better. IMHO it's still confusing to show the Absolute Maximum Ratings value, ask "*What's wrong with that?*" and then explain (correctly) that this value should not be used as the LED current. That's because in English, asking "*What's wrong with that?*" could still be interpreted as a sarcastic suggestion to *use* that value! Personally I would remove all mentions of that value. Or else if you really want to include that value, and then explain not to use it (?!) at least I wouldn't ask "*What's wrong with that?*". Anyway, it's your choice, thanks for the edit :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the datasheet, I see on page 2, Fig. 2 - Forward Current Limit vs. Ambient Temperature, that for ambient temperature up to 60C, the allowable forward current is 100mA.

The 150mA stated in the table must be derated by duty cycle or device cooling to stay within the maximum power dissipation shown in Figure 1,  Power Dissipation 
Limit vs. Ambient Temperature.

Comment: 100mA was what I was thinking the safe bet would be, just not real sure at what voltage and if running continuous is possible or just pulse.

Comment: Per the power dissipation curve, 100mA is safe running continuously.  The forward voltage at 100mA is spec'd at 1.7V max, which is inherent to the LED...not something you set externally.  Regulate the current to 100mA and it will drop no more than 1.7V across it.

Answer (score 0):

Your LED will output infrared light most closely related to current flowing through it. The LED requires *at least* 0.9V across its terminals before **any** current flows (and any light is emitted). At higher currents (and more intense light), voltage across terminals only rises to about 1.5V. Voltage drop is somewhat dependent on temperature.

Pushing the LED to maximum brightness requires a lot of current, which heats the chip, and pushed to extremes, stresses the tiny bonding wires, which can open like a fuse. Data sheet says that chip temperature shouldn't be pushed above 100C.
For continuous use, a data sheet graph defines the safe operating area:
[image: safe operating region]

This graph suggests that you're safe to operate continuously with 100mA LED current, up to an ambient temperature of 60 degrees C.