# UC3842 \$V_{VFB}\$ max rating Vs absolute max rating

Tags: power-electronics, pwm, datasheet, feedback, maximum-ratings

I am having a confusion regarding the DC characteristics absolute max rating and the max rating. The absolute max rating tells that beyond this the IC will not work and will be damaged.

I am confused regarding one point in the datasheet of the [UC3842](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/uc3842) which states that the DC max rating is 2.55 V. Does that mean that if the feedback voltage gets over 2.55 V then the feedback won't work? I feel that the 2.45-2.55 V is a very short range for the IC to work in. Or I am getting this wrong?

Kindly help me understand what they mean here as I have heard that max ratings are those above which the IC won't work but they won't be damaged.

[image]

If 2.5 is the maximum then how is the error found because the input to the op-amp is also 2.5 in the error amplifier?

Comment: This is in the characteristic section, i.e. measured parameters concerning normal device behavior.

Comment: means if the voltage increase beyond 2.5 then the IC works in compensating it to 2.5 V again. The short increase in feedback wount effect at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the definition of absolute maximum ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/324360/what-is-the-definition-of-absolute-maximum-ratings)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3842.pdf):

[image]

According to absolute maximum ratings, damage may occur if voltage on VFB is below -0.3V or above 6.3V.

Now let's look at the internal block diagram:

[image]

We see an error amplifier comparing voltage on VFB to an internal 2.5V reference voltage.

When the chip is in regulation and the feedback loop is operating, the error amplifier will adjust the output PWM so that voltage on VFB is equal to the internal 2.5V reference. You can then use this to design your circuit (for example a voltage divider or something more complicated like isolated feedback from the secondary) so that the output voltage you want corresponds to 2.5V on VFB.

If the chip is not in regulation, voltage on VFB may be different: in this case the error amplifier will be clipped, for example when current limiting is active due to a short on the output.

From "Electrical characteristics":

[image]

This simply describes the accuracy of the internal 2.5V reference. It is typically 2.5V, but over process and temperature variations (see subtext below "Electrical characteristics" heading) that 2.5V may vary in the range specified by Min and Max values. You can then use this to determine the accuracy of your output voltage and its Min/Max guaranteed values.

This is an accuracy spec, it is not like the Absolute Maximum spec which indicates the safe voltage range.

If you use isolated feedback from the secondary with a TL431 and opto for example, then output voltage accuracy will be determined by the TL431, as the UCC chip is inside the TL431 control loop. In this case this accuracy spec is not useful, besides reminding you that voltage on VFB must be around 2.5V for the chip to remain in regulation, so the opto feedback circuitry must ensure this is the case.

Answer (score -2):

It means that if the feedback gets over 2.55 Volt, then the effect is undefined.

It could be that over 2.55, the part draws lots of current. It could be that the input impedance of the feedback point changes. It could be that over 2.55 the feedback goes negative, or becomes unstable. It could just be that feedback over 2.55V has no further effect -- or that over 2.55V it only has a small effect.

The one think it certainly means is that past that voltage, the part is no longer the device defined in the specification.

Amplifiers of all sorts (feedback amplifiers, OP amps, whatever) typically have an input level bounded by the supply voltage. When you get too close to the supply voltage at the input stage of the amplifier, it stops being an amplifier. This doesn't cause destruction of the amplifier: it may be much less than the absolute maximum input voltage.

There are amplifiers that offer "true rail to rail" input: you can buy amplifiers that offer *greater than* rail-to-rail input. But any simple electronic amplifier will have effective input limits that are smaller than the absolute maximum input limits.